# premake5 How do I use multiple configuration files?

Tags: premake

I need different build options for different compilers for a project I am working on. I am thinking of using the dofile keyword to include a different build configuration based on the compiler chosen when using premake5. How do I instruct premake5 to do something like (in pseudo code)

```
if gcc 
 dofile gcc.lua
else if vs2008
 dofile vs2008.lua
else if vs2010
 dofile vs2010.lua
else if vs2012
 dofile vs2012.lua
else if vs2013
 dofile vs2013.lua
else if vs2015
 dofile vs2015.lua
```

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you suggest like this:

```
if _ACTION == "gmake" then
    dofile "gcc.lua"
elseif _ACTION == "vs2008" then
    dofile "vs2008.lua"
elseif ...
```

Or like this:

```
dofile(_ACTION .. ".lua")
```

But you probably want to do this instead:

```
filter { "action:gmake" }
    define { "SOME_GMAKE_SYMBOLS" }
    -- put your gmake configuration here

filter { "action:vs*" }
    -- put your common VS configuration here

filter { "action:vs2008" }
    define { "SOME_VS2008_SYMBOLS" }
    -- put your VS2008 specific configuration here


filter { "action:vs*" }
    -- put your common VS configuration here

-- and so on...
```